# Elasticsearch "ignore_above" issues. Unable use the updated mapping setting after reindex

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-dsl

---

Index Mapping(In Kibana)

- GET /new_index/_mapping
- I already reset the "ignore_above" to the larger size, but it seems not working for my index when I query for searching.
- I heard from other solutions that I need to reindex or reimport the index but i still the same after doing it.
- Can anyone tell me the proper way to doing the reindex or reimport?
- What i did is I delete the index and do mapping first and follow by reindex using logstash
- Is this the correct way to doing it? why "ignored": "library_notes" still will happen?

```
PUT /new_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "items": {
        "type": "nested"
      },
      "contents": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 50000
          }
        }
      },
      "library_notes": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 50000
          }
        }
      },
      "image_path": {
        "type": "text",
        "fielddata": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```
[
  "library_language": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 256
      }
    }
  },
  "library_notes": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 50000
      }
    }
  },
  "library_subject": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
      "keyword": {
        "type": "keyword",
        "ignore_above": 256
      }
    }
  }
]
```

```
Sample library_notes data(is an array)
"library_notes": [
"\"The Big Picture Show, 14 September 2007 - 23 March 2008, Singapore Art Museum\"--T.p. verso.",
"Artists: Wong Shih Yaw; Charlie Co; Entang Wiharso; Syed Thajudeen; Zakaria Omar; Somboon Hormtientong; Lee Hsin Hsin; Dang Xuan Hoa; Lim Tze Peng; Hong Sek Chern; Ferdinand Montemayor; Antonio (Tony) Leano; Wong Keen; Tan Chin Kuan; Pratuang Emjaroen; Jeremy Ramsey; Gao Xingjian; Marc Leguay; He Kongde; Edgar (Egai) Talusan Fernandez; Pacita Abad; Imelda Cajipe-Endaya; Suos Sodavy; Tin Tun Hlaing; Bayu Utomo Radjikin.",
" In putting together The Big picture Show, the Singapore Art Museum (SAM) has taken the opportunity to bring together for display some of its largest treasures in its collection."
],
```

```
the query that i used
{
        "from": 0,
        "size": 10000,
        "track_total_hits": true,
        "sort": [
            {},
            {
                "_script": {
                    "type": "number",
                    "script": {
                        "lang": "painless",
                        "source": "doc.containsKey('image_path') && doc['image_path'].size() > 0 ? 0 : 1"
                    }
                }
            },
            "_score"
        ],
        "query": {
            "function_score": {
                "query": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "match_phrase": {
                                    "category_code": "ART"
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "bool": {
                                    "should": [
                                        {
                                            "wildcard": {
                                                "library_notes.keyword": {
                                                    "value": "lim *ze peng",
                                                    "case_insensitive": true
                                                }
                                            }
                                        },
                                        {
                                            "wildcard": {
                                                "linking_notes.keyword": {
                                                    "value": "lim *ze peng",
                                                    "case_insensitive": true
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            },
                            
                            {
                                "match": {
                                    "is_available": true
                                }
                            },
                        ],
                        "should": []
                    }
                },
                "functions": [
                    {
                        "random_score": {},
                        "weight": 1
                    }
                ],
                "score_mode": "sum"
            }
        }
    },
}
```

the wildcard search that "lim *tze peng" cannot be found, even though there is a Lim Tze Peng inside the library_notes field

Comment: I have already answered this question the last time you asked it. If you are not happy with the answer please add more information to your question there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77334631/elasticsearch-ignore-above-issues